# Summing Term over only edges involving a particular node

Tags: graph-theory, notation, article-writing

I've got a quick notation question.

Currently I'm trying to do a sum over all edges of a graph as so:
$$
\sum_{i, j\ \in {E}}^{m}\frac{J_{i j}}{4}Z_{i}
$$

What notation would indicate I only wanted to sum the terms over edges connected to the node $i$ ?
This doesn't seem right as it has the subscript $j$, which isn't referenced at all.

$$
\sum_{i\ \in {E}}^{m}\frac{J_{i j}}{4}Z_{i}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{j: \{i,j\}\in E}\cdots$$